# How to add two hexadecimal number in assembly language?

Tags: math, assembly, sum, addition

I am trying to add two hexadecimal number in assembly language.one is 0fh(decimal 15) another is 0eh(decimal 14).I am getting the sum =00011101 which is the  binary of decimal 29.But my expected result was 00101001(where 0010 is the  binary value of 2 and and 1001 is the binary value of 9).Here is my code:

```
name "add-sub"

org 100h

mov al, 0fh       ; hex=0fh=dec15  
mov bl, 0eh      ; hex=0eh=dec14

add bl,al

mov cx, 8
print: mov ah, 2   ; print function. interupt er subfunction
       mov dl, '0'
       test bl, 10000000b  ; test first bit.
       jz zero
       mov dl, '1'
zero:  int 21h; find interupt  subfunction
       shl bl, 1
loop print

; print hexa suffix:
mov dl, 'h'
int 21h

; wait for any key press:
mov ah, 0
int 16h

ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the result as a packed BCD-number, but this is not the normal operating modus of the CPU. So you have to convert the result. In your case you can do it with `AAM`:

Replace

```
add bl,al
```

by

```
add al,bl         ; Result in AL
aam               ; AL => AH (first digit) AL (second digit) (unpacked BCD)
shl ah, 4         ; Prepare AH for ORing
or al, ah         ; AL to packed BCD
mov bl, al        ; Copy to BL for following loop
```

Comment: Excellent!if i am not wrong after the OR Al=00101001 that means we have gained our expected result then why we need the rest of the loop ?What was the problem if we directly print the value ?

Comment: @user2252617: You need the loop to convert the result to printable ASCII values ('0' and '1'). Please consider that I **only** corrected the code according to your question, there a other issues to handle ;-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.one thing is confusing me when i am adding two numbers add al,bl(al=3,bl=2)  what is the value of al? is it in decimal format(5) or binary format(00000101)?if the value is in binary format then how  shl ah,4 is working here(as far i know after diving  29 by 10  quotient 2 is mov to ah and reminder 9 to al ) ? and if the value is decimal format then how it will be tested with a binary value ? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: @user2252617: You need a good tutorial ;-). Just one thing: `AL` is a bunch of electrical states anywhere in the CPU. "0fh" or "15" or "000.." are just human descriptions of this states. You choose that description which fits your needs best. So the CPU has no problem to test a "decimal" value with a "binary" value. Conversions are mostly made to prepare the bunch of electrical states for another machine like a display or a printer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the well defined explanation!Can you help little more ?what to do if i want to get the result in hexadecimal (that menas 1d which is the hexadecimal of 29)?